# Spring Boot not loading @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I am developing a Spring boot application where I am trying to configure custom properties for a bean which gives the suppourted extensions for my file .
When I run the application it runs sucessfully with 0 errors but the extensions are not loaded from the application.properties file.

Here is my code in application.properties :-----

```
suppourted.extensions[0]="jpg"
suppourted.extensions[1]="pdf"
suppourted.extensions[2]="png"
```

Here is the code of the bean:--

```
package com.MyBoot.FirstBoot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "suppourted")
public class SuppourtedFiles {

    private List<String> extensions=new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String>getExtensions() {
        return extensions;
    }

    public void setExtensions(List<String>extensions) {
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SuppourtedFiles [extensions=" + extensions.size() + "]";
    }

}
```

My main SpringBootApplication:----

```
package com.MyBoot.FirstBoot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication

public class FirstBoot1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstBoot1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I do not understand where the problem is occuring. Kindly help me.

Update:--

I want to send that object to my jsp page for displaying it using model not just create that bean in CommandLineRunner

Comment: How are you trying to access the value you have set in the properties file? Using the @Value?

Comment: No I am using the @ConfigurationProperties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below will work,

**Applications:**

```java
package com.MyBoot.FirstBoot;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SuppourtedFiles.class)
public class FirstBoot1Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final SuppourtedFiles suppourtedFiles;

    public FirstBoot1Application(SuppourtedFiles suppourtedFiles) {
        this.suppourtedFiles = suppourtedFiles;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(suppourtedFiles);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstBoot1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Configuration Class:**

```java
package com.MyBoot.FirstBoot;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "suppourted")
public class SuppourtedFiles {

    private List<String> extensions = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getExtensions() {
        return extensions;
    }

    public void setExtensions(List<String> extensions) {
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.MyBoot.FirstBoot.SuppourtedFiles [extensions=" + Arrays.toString(extensions.toArray()) + "]"; // Changed to check if array is filled from spring or not.
    }

}
```

**minimum maven dependencies**

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Optional Dependency for annotation processor:**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

> **Please make sure your project packaging is jar or war**

**Controller:**

```java
@RestController
public class SampleController {
    private final SuppourtedFiles suppourtedFiles;

    public SampleController(SuppourtedFiles suppourtedFiles) {
        this.suppourtedFiles = suppourtedFiles;
    }

    @GetMapping("/extensions")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> extensions(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(suppourtedFiles.getExtensions());
    }
}
```

**Controller Dependency:**

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: how packaging is related ?

Comment: It has worked .Can you give me basic explanation or refrence of this works

Comment: Also I want to sent the object of it to my jsp page for rendering to show it in form:select to the users so by this method it is not working.Kindly help me with this too

Comment: What do you change in your project?

Comment: My project has been like this

Comment: @YogendraR , what the result of your project is matter, if it's pom, there is no jar result for it, i mean there is no bytecode.

Comment: Sir please help me also

Comment: You should have a controller class to retrieve those properties from server.

Comment: @IbrahimAlTamimi I meant, it could be a war as well

Comment: Yes I have a controller class

Comment: Can you please specify the sample code for me because I am a newbie to Spring and this all is confusing a lot

Comment: @YogendraR Ooh sorry, I forget the war. because I'm not working a lot with war packaging. sorry for that.

Comment: @VedantGandhi check the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you should either use

`@Configuration`

in your SuppourtedFiles class or

`@EnableConfigurationProperties(SuppourtedFiles.class)`

in your FirstBoot1Application.

Comment: I have done trying both but still it is not working and also after Spring Boot 2.2 automatically detects it using classpath so we dont have to use those annotations externally

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `@Configuration` on the `SuppourtedFiles` class and also the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on the `FirstBoot1Application` class and add the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor` dependency.

```
package com.MyBoot.FirstBoot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "suppourted")
public class SuppourtedFiles {
    //You should not create the extensions object just declare it
    private List<String> extensions;

    public List<String>getExtensions() {
        return extensions;
    }
    public void setExtensions(List<String>extensions) {
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.MyBoot.FirstBoot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class FirstBoot1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstBoot1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And also in the properties you do not need double quotes. You can just have,

```
suppourted.extensions[0]=jpg
suppourted.extensions[1]=pdf
suppourted.extensions[2]=png
```